# Moped "invalid collection name"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid3, moped

I've recently upgraded mongoid to version 3.0.0 from 2.0 in my rails app.
When performing an operation which saves an object (either existing or a new one) I'm getting `Moped::Errors::OperationFailure: The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Command` saying that there is `invalid collection name"` .

full_collection_name for the object returns `foo_development.$cmd`, `Mongoid.default_session.collections` returns empty array but when i access the database through the mongo client, all the collections are in place.

my mongoid.yml

`development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: foo_development
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've moved from rails 3.1.3 to rails 3.2.21 and upgraded to mongoid 3.1.1 with mongo 2.2.6 along with bson 4.0 which solved the issue